# How to get the difference of two multidimensional arrays with different keys but same value in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two multidimensional arrays below.

### 1St Array

```
Array
(
    [ma] => Array
        (
            [mdesktopapps] => Array
                (
                    [0] => part1
                    [1] => part2
                )

        )

)
```

### 2nd Array

```
Array
(
    [ma] => Array
        (
            [mdesktopapps] => Array
                (
                    [0] => part2
                )

        )

)
```

I want to get the difference between the above arrays and the output should be like below

### Desired Output

```
Array
(
    [ma] => Array
        (
            [mdesktopapps] => Array
                (
                    [0] => part1
                )

        )

)
```

I have tried to get the output using the below function but not getting the proper output.

### Function which I have used

```
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2) {
    $difference=array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            if( !isset($array2[$key]) || !is_array($array2[$key]) ) {
                $difference[$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                if( !empty($new_diff) )
                    $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
            }
        } else if( !array_key_exists($key,$array2) || $array2[$key] !== $value ) {
            $difference[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $difference;
}
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [ma] => Array
        (
            [mdesktopapps] => Array
                (
                    [0] => part1
                    [1] => part2
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: When you say _"with different keys"_, do you mean only the bottom level, numeric keys? Also, are there more associative keys inside your array where you wish to perform this operation or is `mdesktopapps` the only one?

Comment: yes the bottom level numiric keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the logic you put inside the else if condition:

```
...
} else if( !array_key_exists($key,$array2) || $array2[$key] !== $value ) {
...
```

Now what you do here is, you call the method for 2nd time where you pass your 'ma' arrays, and you start iterating the values - "part1" and "part2", you get inside this else if and for first value "part1" you meat this condition $array2[$key] !== $value, because in $array2[$key] ($array2[0]) value is "part2" and $value in this first iteration is "part1", so you assign this value to the $difference[]. So far so good, but during the second iteration, where value is "part2" you actually meet this condition - !array_key_exists($key,$array2), because your $array2 doesn't have key 1 so you add to $difference[] this result as well ... What you can do:

```
// now i've added 3rd argument to the function called recursiveCount 
// by default is false so this count happens only if you pass true as 3rd arg
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($a, $b, $recursiveCount = false) {
        // by default we set $array1 to be $a and $array2 to be $b 
        $array1 = $a;
        $array2 = $b;
       // but if we "put the count flag" and if the first array we pass
       // is smaller that the 2nd we will reverse it
       // so you don't have to worry about if the 1st array you pass in the function is smaller than the 2nd
    if ($recursiveCount && (count($array1, COUNT_RECURSIVE) < count($array2, COUNT_RECURSIVE))) {
        $array1 = $b;
        $array2 = $a;
    }

        $difference = [];
        foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                if (!isset($array2[$key]) || !is_array($array2[$key])) {
                    $difference[$key] = $value;
                } else {

                    // now note that now when we call the function here we dont pass the 3rd argument, to count our arrays
                    $newDiff = $this->array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                    if (!empty($newDiff)) {
                        $difference[$key] = $newDiff;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // also 1 small change here just in case arr2 is not an array actually
                if (is_array($array2) && !in_array($value, $array2)) {
                    $difference[] = $value;
                } elseif (!is_array($array2) && $value != $array2) {
                    $difference[] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        return $difference;
    }
```

Now how to use it with this 3rd param:

```
    $aa = [
        "ma" => [
            "mdesktopapps" => ["part1","part2","part3","part4","part5"]
        ]
    ];

    $ab = [
        "ma" => [
            "mdesktopapps" => ["part2","part5","part4"]
        ]
    ];

    // note we pass true as 3rd arg, so we will count our multidimensional arrays
   // and because $ab < $aa they will be switched in out function
    $t = $this->array_diff_assoc_recursive($ab, $aa, true);

    var_dump($t);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  'ma' =>
  array(1) {
    'mdesktopapps' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(5) "part1"
      [1] =>
      string(5) "part3"
    }
  }
}
```

That's it, from here you can play with it and upgrade it even more ...

Comment: Wow Angel, it worked, Thanks a lot. Let me check it with some different arrays.

Comment: I've made a little edit of the function so you don't worry which array is bigger and will put an example of use

Answer (score -1):

For this problem you can use [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function like:

```
<?php
$arr1 = [
    "ma" => [
        "mdesktopapps" => [
            0 => "part1",
            1 => "part2"
        ],
    ],
];

$arr2 = [
    "ma" => [
        "mdesktopapps" => [
            0 => "part2"
        ],
    ],
];


$result = [
    "ma" => [
        "mdesktopapps" => array_intersect(
            $arr1['ma']['mdesktopapps'], 
            $arr2['ma']['mdesktopapps']
        )
    ],
];

print_r($result);
```

[here can test this PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=3495bb5f409617242b46324025d85297&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: This will not work in my case as the keys 'ma' or 'mdesktopapp' can be different. The solution should be dynamic using loop or some recursive functions.